# Setting currentTime is not working while streaming audio via http

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I'm streaming audio using http. I'm loading the audio using the following code.

```
var audio = new Audio("http://example.com/get/stream/1/wav");
function seek(time){
    audio.currentTime = time;
}
```

The browser can play the audio format.

I'm running a nodejs express server to serve the audio file. Below is a simplified version of the code that is handling the stream.

```
app.get("/get/stream/:id/:format", function(req, res){
    //Here was some code to verify the request, this code doesn't affect this question so I left it out

    var stat = fs.statSync(__dirname+"/path/to/file/here.wav");

    res.header("Content-Type", "audio/wav");
    res.header("Content-Length", stat.size);

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname+"/path/to/file/here.wav");
    readStream.pipe(res);
});
```

If I load a normal audio file (one that doesn't use http streaming) the seek function will work normally, but if I use an audio file that does use http streaming the song will just jump to the beginning.

I need to use http streaming because some files are extremely large and compressing/transcoding them to a smaller size is no option?

**So my question is:** How can I change the current time of an audio file that uses http streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser needs to know that seeking is allowed.

Try adding:

```
res.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
```

Alternatively, as you are using Node Express, you could add a plug-in that helps with seeking, such as [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send-seekable).